# Automatically convert project to use either tabs or spaces for identation, not both

Tags: gratis, linux, windows-10, source-code

I have a project consisting of ~25 source files, spread across three directories (all .java, if that matters). I have a problem with inconsistent indentation, however. Both tabs and spaces are used throughout the project, sometimes even in the same file. I'm looking for a tool that will either replace all spaces with tabs, or vise-versa.

**Requirements:**

- gratis
- Ability to choose between tabs and spaces (I'm fine with using more than one tool
- Works with either Windows 10 or GNU/Linux
- Works with more than one file/directory at a time
- Works somewhat reliably (I don't want to have to end up going through all my code reformatting it to look "pretty")
- Works with Java code (preferably works on any/most source code)

*Preferably open source, but not required.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## IntelliJ or Eclipse

Both are free and you can do that.

By the way you should use an IDE if you develop in Java ;-)

Comment: How would I do this in IntelliJ?

Comment: I found a way to indent line-by-line (ctrl + alt + i), but still havent found out how to indent the entire project yet.

Comment: @hhaslam11 the help pages for IntelliJ are a good help https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/reformatting-source-code.html